# Using expressjs, is there a way to use mammoth to not use a path?

Tags: node.js, express, docx

As the question states, is there a way to use mammoth so that it doesn’t require writing to disk? I see the following package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");

mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "path/to/document.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
        var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
    })
    .done();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `mammoth` document, the first parameter of `convertToHtml` function is `input`, with `input` is an object describing the source document. On node.js, they supported `{path: path}` and `{buffer: buffer}` (or `{arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer}`).

You can convert the uploaded file to a buffer then push the buffer to `convertToHtml` function.